# Manage LAT + LON as variables to get DISTANCE

Tags: react-native, object, variables

I have working snack with my geolocation, lat + lon. I'm trying to add the getDistance and isPointInCircle functions, they both work until I want to substitute a point with myLAT + myLON.

With good help I've been recomended to declare "const { latitude, longitude } = this.state;" but I'm missing something because I still get errors. I tried putting the functions inside and outside "componentDidMount()" but I'm not able to make it work.

```
import geolib from "geolib";

export default class App extends Component {

 constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state = {
  latitude: null,
  longitude: null,
  speed: null,
  error: null,
};
  }    

  componentDidMount() {
  this.watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
  (position) => {
   const { latitude, longitude } = this.state;        
      this.setState({
      latitude: position.coords.latitude,
      longitude: position.coords.longitude,
      speed: position.coords.speed,
      error: null,
    });

  },
  (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
  { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 0, distanceFilter: 1},
);
}

  componentWillUnmount() {
  navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(this.watchId);
  }

  render() {
  return (  
     <View style={styles.container}>  
    <View style={{ flexGrow: 0.3, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>          
     <Text>GeoLib:: Distance: {DIST} meters</Text> //I'd like to put the DISTANCE here 
     {this.state.error ? <Text>Error: {this.state.error}</Text> : null}           
     </View>                  
);
  }
}

  let RADIUS = geolib.isPointInCircle(                 
       { latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude },
       {latitude: 37.600530, longitude: -122.482629},
        1000
    );

   let DIST = geolib.getDistance(
       { latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude },
       {latitude: 37.600530, longitude: -122.482629}
       );

   if(RADIUS == true){
       console.log("I am in Radius.");
   }else{
       console.log("I am NOT in Radius.");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access values that are in state you need to use `this.state.key`. You are trying to access values from state without the proper notation. You are also just adding values outside of your component that rely on values inside your component, that is not going to work.

Here is how I would implement your component, this is just one of many different ways that your component could be refactored.

```
// other import statements eg React etc. 
import geolib from 'geolib';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      latitude: null,
      longitude: null,
      speed: null,
      distance: null,
      radius: null,
      error: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
      (position) => {
        const { latitude, longitude, speed } = position.coords;
        const center = { latitude: 37.600530, longitude: -122.482629 };
        const { radius, distance } = this.calculateMeasurements(latitude, longitude, center);

        this.setState({
          latitude: latitude,
          longitude: longitude,
          speed: speed,
          radius: radius,
          distance: distance,
          error: null
        });
      },
      (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
      { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 0, distanceFilter: 1 }
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(this.watchId);
  }

  /*
   * latitude: user's latitude
   * longitude: user's longitude
   * center: center of the circle eg: { latitude: 37.600530, longitude: -122.482629 }
   * this function is now reusable you don't have to hard code the center coordinates
   */
  calculateMeasurements = (latitude, longitude, center) => {
    const radius = geolib.isPointInCircle(
      { latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude },
      { latitude: center.latitude, longitude: center.longitude },
      1000
    );
    const distance = geolib.getDistance(
      { latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude },
      { latitude: center.latitude, longitude: center.longitude }
    );
    console.log(radius, distance);
    return { radius, distance };
  }

  render () {
    const { radius, distance } = this.state;

    if (radius === true) {
      console.log('I am in Radius.');
    } else if (radius === null) {
      console.log('Radius has not been calculated');
    } else if (radius === false) {
      console.log('I am NOT in Radius.');
    }

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={{ flexGrow: 0.3, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          <Text>GeoLib:: Distance: {distance !== null ? distance : 'unknown'} meters</Text>
          {this.state.error ? <Text>Error: {this.state.error}</Text> : null}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

1. Add radius and distance initial values to state
2. Remove getting the latitude and longitude values in the componentDidMount, they are null and you aren't using the values anywhere.
3. Deconstruct the latitude, longitude and speed from the position.coords. This saves you have to type `position.coords.key` every time you want to use a value from it.
4. Create a helper function `calculateMeasurements`, that will calculate the `radius` and `distance` values that you want. Call it in the `componentDidMount` using the coordinates that you have just found. Then save the `radius` and `distance` to the state in the `componentDidMount`
5. Update `render` so that it uses the values from the state.
6. Fix the missing `</View>` tag in the `render`
7. Remove the `let RADIUS = ...` and other calculations from the bottom as they are not valid in this place.

Comment: you are great! So clear, that's better than what I was looking for!
Thanks again!